# Styling my listbox in xaml

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0, listbox, coding-style

I've just been fooling around with a ListBox control that I want to style a certain way. For now it looks just like I want it to with rounded corners and no padding. However, the rounded corners seems to cause a problem with the items in the ListBox.

A screenshot so you can see what I mean: 
[alt text http://www.bo-mortensen.dk/listbox.JPG](http://www.bo-mortensen.dk/listbox.JPG)

The thing is, that the first and the last item in the listbox needs to have it's corners rounded aswell. So the first item in the listbox needs to have it's upper left and right corners rounded while the bottom corners needs to be rectangular.

Is it possible in some way, to make three different styles and have the first, middle and last items use their own style? So i.e:

- First item uses style: ListBoxFirstItem
- Middle items uses style: ListBoxMiddleItems
- Last item uses style: ListBoxLastItem

Also, as a side question, how am I able to style the selected item and mouse over? If i'd like to get rid of the blue rectangle that's standard.

Hope you understand my question(s), if not - just let me know and I'll see if I can elaborate :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if the items need to scroll? Do you sill only want the last item to have rounded bottom corners or is the last __visibile__ item that should?

Comment: Good point, Anthony :)

I think it should be only the last item to have it's bottom corners be rounded and not the last visible item. If that makes any sense? :)

Comment: No one? :/ been trying to do this since yesterday, but with no results at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is an [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx).
this allows you to have different templates for different items in the listbox based on whatever criteria you specify.

[check Dr. WPF](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/01/03/itemscontrol-d-is-for-datatemplate/) for a pretty decent example (about 1/2 way down the page)
another tutorial is at [Switch On The Code](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector)
and everybody's favorite, [Bea Stollnitz](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=16)

Comment: Hey Muad'Dib, thanks for your reply! :) Greatly appreciated. Million-dollar question here: does DataTemplateSelector also work in Silverlight?

Comment: Seems that the ItemTemplateSelector is not present in Silverlight :(

Comment: sorry, missed the silverlight part. :(

Comment: No problem, was me who forgot to tag my question with Silverlight :) Thanks for your help though!